Identify this show about teenagers chatting with a mysterious character
This is a show that I used to watch in the early 90s.
I can't remember the back story of the main plot device, but there is someone who is communicating with a group of teenage kids via a computer chat. (Back in the early 90s, this was something new and totally interesting).
The kids would type something, and the person would reply to them.
In each episode, they would be trying to uncover a mystery. There is no crimes, or deaths, but mysteries that are somehow educational to English language learners. 
I still don't know if they meet with the person who types on the computer or not.
Come to think of it, this person might have some power to communicate with the kids outside of the computer screen. They would see letters re-arrange in a newspaper maybe, or a cereal bowl, or something like that. Not sure though.

This sounds exactly like Ghostwriter.

Ghostwriter is an American children's mystery television series created by Liz Nealon and produced by the Children's Television Workshop (now known as Sesame Workshop) and BBC One. It began airing on PBS on October 4, 1992, and the final episode aired on February 12, 1995. The series revolves around a close-knit circle of friends from Brooklyn who solve neighborhood crimes and mysteries as a team of young detectives with the help of an invisible ghost named Ghostwriter. Ghostwriter can communicate with the kids only by manipulating whatever text and letters he can find and using them to form words and sentences

It sometimes communicated with them through a computer, IIRC. There was also a brief attempt to revive it called The New Ghostwriter Mysteries in 1997. Here's the original intro:



